# テキストエディターのAtomでファイルを開いた時にツリービューを表示させないようにするにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: atom-editor

テキストエディターのAtomでファイルを開いた時にツリービューを表示させないようにするにはどうすればいいですか？

また、起動時に前回開いていたファイルの状態を保ったまま起動することはできますか？

Answer (score 1):

設定できますよ。
[Settings > Open Empty Editor On Start](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-start-atom-without-loading-last-files-projects-e-g-how-delete-storage-editor-files-on-startup/27223)